# Hiding Master View Controler (UISplitViewController) on iOS7 with iOS8.2 SDK

Tags: ios, ipad, hide, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm creating application for iOS7.0 and higher versions. But due [this](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a) i must use iOS8 SDK. But since iOS8 UISplitViewController delegate method "shouldHideViewController" is deprecated. So basically APPLE removed any known to me method to hide masterVC for iOS7 users..

Please tell me is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction)
 property on the detail VC.

```
self.splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0;
```

Comment: Well i have tried it but i get a crash while runing on simulator (iOS7.1)  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Windhager.SplitViewController setPreferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: ahh yes.... preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction
Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
I basically need what is available in iOS7 and iOS8